# Creating a method that returns a number range?

Tags: java, methods

I need to take in a start and end range of numbers from the user and make a method which returns the number range to the user inclusive e.g. `1, 2, 3, 4`

My method returns the values including the final value twice, I think because I have my return type set here. Is there a way I can alter my method to work better?

```
class Test

{


    public static void main ( String[] args )

    {

        //Setup a Scanner
        Scanner scan = new Scanner ( System.in ) ;

        //Declare Variables
        byte startNum = 0 ;
        byte endNum = 0 ;

        //Get User Input//
        System.out.println ( " Please enter the starting range: " ) ;
        startNum = scan.nextByte() ;

        System.out.println ( " Please enter the final range: " ) ;
        endNum = scan.nextByte() ;

        //Call method
        System.out.println ( numberPrinter ( startNum, endNum ) ) ;


    }

    // A method to print out all the numbers between startNum and endNum.
    static byte numberPrinter ( byte a, byte b )

        {
            byte range = 0 ;

            while ( a <= b )

                {
                    range = a ;
                    System.out.println ( range ) ;
                    a++ ;

                }

            return range ;

        }
```

Comment: 1. if you're working with int why are you using `byte` ?
2. instead of wrapping the call to `numberPrinter ` with `System.out.println` simply call `numberPrinter ` and set all the printing to be done from there.

Comment: If your goal really is to create a method that **returns** a number range then your approach is completly wrong. Your method currently returns a byte, but it **prints** a number range.

Comment: The number must be below 100 so I used byte since it only allows for +127 numbers. Okay I have removed the System.out.println but why does that stop the final range from printing twice?

Comment: It printed the last number inside the numberPrint method and the second time when the method returned the last value (in the main functuon)

Comment: Okay so it prints 1-4 with numberPrinter ( startNum, endNum ) and then the return range sends the final value of 4 and it appeared because I told it to with  System.out.println () ?

Answer (score 3):

The method numberPrinter prints all the number from the startNum to endNum so there is not point in printing the return value of the method.

Simply remove the print from the line:

```
System.out.println ( numberPrinter ( startNum, endNum ) ) ;
```

to:

```
numberPrinter ( startNum, endNum )
```

Comment: This works but why! shouldn't it still print the final value twice because of the return range;  Also is my logic good in my method, I want to try and learn good habits from the beginning.

Comment: The value is printed to the screen only when you use the println method. When we removed the call in the last line of the main functiont, the only place the program printed the values is inside the numberPrint method. This method prints each number one time

Comment: You should use integers instead of bytes and change the method as @Wasi Ahmad suggested

Comment: Would using int not be a waste of memory as the user is suppose to be entering a range of only 1-100?

Answer (score 1):

Change the return type of the `numberPrinter()` function to `void` and avoid printing the return value from `numberPrinter()` inside `main()` function. Simply call the `numberPrinter()` function. Note that, you don't need a variable `range` inside `numberPrinter()` function, you can directly use the variable `a`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // your code goes here

    //Call method
    numberPrinter(startNum, endNum);
}

// A method to print out all the numbers between startNum and endNum.
static void numberPrinter(byte a, byte b) {
    while (a <= b) {
        System.out.println(a);
        a++;
    }
}
```

If you are interested to return all the numbers in the given range from `numberPrinter()` to `main()` and then print, you can do the following.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // your code goes here

    //Call method
    byte[] result = numberPrinter(startNum, endNum);
    for (byte value : result) {
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}

// A method to return all the numbers between startNum and endNum.
static byte[] numberPrinter(byte a, byte b) {
    byte[] range = new byte[b - a + 1];
    for (byte i = a; i <= b; i++) {
        range[i - a] = i;
    }
    return range;
}
```

Comment: Okay I will save this code snippet, I need to use my own code since it is my first attempt but will save this as best practice.

Comment: @Ninja2k i appreciate, you can see my update in the answer in case you are interested to return values from the method `numberPrinter()`.

Answer (score 0):

You're printing the return value of `numberPrinter()`, which is the last value. Remove the last print statement from `main()` and change the return type to `void`:

```
public static void main ( String[] args )

{

    //...

    //Call method
    numberPrinter ( startNum, endNum ) ;


}

// A method to print out all the numbers between startNum and endNum.
static void numberPrinter ( byte a, byte b )

    {

        while ( a <= b )

            {
                System.out.println ( a++ ) ;

            }

    }
```

Comment: I did not realise you could use void with a method that accepts two byte parameters. Will try this soon.

Answer (score 0):

Ask the user to input a number a and b and use a `while` that shows you an 
`a++` until `a < b`